# How to integrate MaterializeCss with Foundation 6 - Zurb Template?

Tags: npm, sass, materialize, zurb-foundation-6

I would like to add [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) or something similar to a Foundation 6 [Zurb Template](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html) build. Is it possible to add just the sass styes? How could that be done?

There is also [Material Foundation](https://github.com/eucalyptuss/material-foundation), but it uses grunt instead of gulp. Would this cause a conflict? How is it added to the Zurb Template? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just css/scss, you can just copy the files to your project and import them using sass partials.

```
// Copied file: _material.scss

@import "path/to/file"; // No file ext or leading _
```

Edit: Whether or not gulp and grunt conflict depends on how you have things set up. If they both work with the same files I could see them conflicting.